# How can I create a file's full path if it does not exist?

Tags: linux, perl, file, file-io, perl-module

In a function I get a reference to a file. That could be in a format `dir1/subdir/filename.txt`
Is there a way in perl to do:

1. If the file does not exist, create it **and** the directory structure as
   well if it does not exist
2. This way guarantees that if 2 scripts try to do the same 
   concurrently nothing will go wrong (e.g. end up with
   corrupted/locked file etc)?

Comment: You should look into [`File::Path`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3APath) and `flock`, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

1. To check whether file exists or not , you can do

`my $filename="dir1/subdir/filename.txt";`

```
if (-e $filename)
{
  print "file exists";
  open( FILE, '<', $filename ) or die 'Could not open file:  ' . $!;

}

elsif (!-e $filename)
{
print "file does not exist";

}
```

Both -e and -f can be used to check file exists or not
 2.To avoid conflict, I think you can create file with time of creation in filename. But, I'm not sure if you can create with the same.

Comment: `-e` checks whether a file or directory exists. Although it's unlikely that a directory is named `filename.txt`, you should use `-f` to check whether a *file* exists.